# why isn't my catalog loading remote repositories in icp?

Tags: dns, ibm-cloud-private

I'm able to load local repo charts in ICP but unable to load remote ones.

The link is definitely up because I can ping the address and it works on another ICP environment but not this one

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have **valid nameservers** in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

The kubernetes cluster sets up its own DNS server using skydns, running in the kube-dns pod. When that pod starts it reads the /etc/resolv.conf file in the host server and uses that information to set up skydns.

Look at the helm-api logs first and see if you get any name resolution errors, which indicates there is a DNS problem.
The kube-dns logs may come into play depending on the situation.

Kudos to James G. for the discovery.